# SQL to reconcile two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables ItemSold and ItemInventory, and am trying to create a query that will check if the ItemSold SUM(quantity of an item) is balanced against ItemInventory.

```
ItemSold
sale_id | item_id | quantity | conversion |
--------  -------   ---------  ----------  
  1099       1         1.00       1.00
  1099       1         1.00       0.50
  1099       2         1.00       1.00
```

I'm using the conversion column to signify a retail/smaller unit of an item

```
ItemInventory
  id |   description | quantity
-----   ------------   --------
  1        Item1         100.00
  2        Item2         100.00
```

Below is a query that I created to check if there are items that if you SUM up is greater than the quantity on the ItemInventory.

```
SELECT ItemSold.item_id, ItemSold.quantity, ItemSold.conversion
FROM ItemSold 
INNER JOIN ItemInventory 
ON ItemSold.item_id = ItemInventory.id
WHERE Itemsold.sale_id = @saleid
GROUP BY ItemSold.item_id, ItemSold.quantity, ItemSold.conversion 
HAVING SUM(ItemSold.quantity * ItemSold.conversion) > SUM(ItemInventory.quantity)
```

It works but it compares the quantity of EACH ROW on the ItemSold rather than the SUM(quantity group by item_id).

My goal is to not process the Sale transaction unless there is enough inventory regardless what unit the item is sold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strategy of this query is to aggregate, for each item, the total quantity promised to be sold in the `ItemSold` table, and then compare this number against the inventory number which is available.  Items not having sufficient quantity are displayed in the result set.

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.description
FROM ItemInventory t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT item_id, SUM(quantity*conversion) AS quantity_sold
    FROM ItemSold
    GROUP BY item_id
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.item_id
WHERE t1.quantity < COALESCE(t2.quantity_sold, 0)
```

Comment: you used three column in t2 clause but group by item_id only. I think this won't work. Is that you forgot the sum?

Comment: @Ming I forgot to take the `SUM()`, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This will check that all the items are in the inventory for the `sale_id` of 1099:

```
SELECT sale_id,
       MIN( CASE WHEN s.total_quantity <= i.quantity THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
         AS can_process_order
FROM   ( SELECT sale_id,
                item_id,
                SUM( quantity ) AS total_quantity
         FROM   itemsold
         WHERE  sale_id = 1099
         GROUP BY sale_id, item_id
       ) s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       iteminventory i
       ON ( s.item_id = i.id )
GROUP BY sale_id;
```

It will output `1` if there are sufficient items and `0` if any one item does not have enough stock.

To perform the update you can do:

```
MERGE INTO iteminventory dst
USING (
  SELECT i.ROWID AS rid,
         total_sale,
         MIN( CASE WHEN total_sale <= quantity THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY sale_id ) AS can_process_sale
  FROM   (
    SELECT sale_id,
           item_id,
           SUM( quantity ) AS total_sale
    FROM   itemsold
    WHERE  sale_id = 1099
    GROUP BY sale_id, item_id
  ) s
  LEFT OUTER JOIN iteminventory i
  ON ( i.id = s.item_id )
) src
ON ( src.rid = dst.ROWID AND src.can_process_sale = 1 )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET quantity = quantity - total_sale;
```